# How can i delete the prime numbers out of a stack

Tags: c, stack

i don`t know the steps of deleting prime numbers out of a stack st[10] using the functions pop and push

```
void pop(int *st,int*vf)
{
    vf--;
}
void push(int *st,int *vf,int nrnou)
{
    st[vf]=nrnou;
    vf++;

}
```

Comment: Which part don't you know: how to identify prime numbers, or how to remove them from a stack?

Comment: For `int *st` and `int *vf`, `st[vf]` is  a constraint violation. C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
Constraints
1
One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object type’’, the other
expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’.*

Comment: The second function has syntax errors, perhaps it should be `st[*vf]=nrnou; (*vf)++;`. The first is similarly incorrect and also discards the popped value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary stack.

Pop all entries from original stack and, if not prime, push them into the temporary stack (discarding prime entries).

Then do the opposite: pop from temporary stack and push into the original stack.